# Alfresco Upload Webscript

Tags: json, upload, alfresco, web-scripting

I want to use the backend webScript `/alfresco/service/api/upload` to upload a file. But the problem is that I have no Idea what the JSON that I have to send on POST should looks like. However I know what are the parameters :

```
- filedata, (mandatory) HTML type file You must specify one of: 
  destination (the folder NodeRef where the node will be created) 
  updateNodeRef (the NodeRef of an existing node that will be updated) 
- siteid and containerid (the Site name and the container in that site where the document will be  created)
- uploaddirectory : name of the folder (either in the site container or the destination) where the     document will be uploaded. This folder must already exist
- description : Description for a version update (versionDescription)
- contenttype : The content type that this document should be specialised to
- majorversion
- overwrite
- thumbnails
```

Now what I need is the JSON format. What the file content should look like (stream or plain/text?). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that API takes JSON? I thought it worked with HTML Form Posts?

Comment: Yes I am. It definitely accept JSON as request.

Comment: You sure? It supports reporting the result by JSON, but [looking at the source code for it](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/remote-api/config/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/upload/upload.post.js) I only see references to HTML form uploads on the input side

Answer (score 1):

The mandatory field are :

- "filedata" : is a `FileSystemResource` (JAVA)
- destination : is the nodeRef of the folder.
- uploaddirectory : is the destination directory inside that nodeRef.

The other fields are optional.

**Upldate :**

Here is an example of an upload to alfresco repositoy in JAVA [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23824768/2423198). In the example they use `siteid` and `containerid` these field replace `destination` and are successively the site name and and the folder inside that site.